# How to call Javascript function mutipletimes

Tags: javascript, html

I want to call this Javascript function everytimes I check the checkbox,So, I put `onclick=myFunction()` in input tag. But when I use the page I can call `myFunction()` only one time at the first checkbox.
So,in my website, it has about 400-500 question same like example

My objective is create quiz website that can show the answer after I answer the question from checking in checkbox.

**P.S**  I am new for HTML and javascript, if you have a better idea, please suggest me

```js
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
   

<div class="cssExTopic" >Question Number 1 :  
    <ul><li>This is Question Topic</li></ul></div>
    <div class="cssExChoice">
      <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()"> 1 : CD-ROM</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()"> 2 : HARD DISK</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()"> 3 : SDRAM</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()"> 4 : REGISTER</li>
        <li>Answer
          <font id="text" style="display: none;">: 4</font>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Element `id`s must be unique across the entire document

Comment: Since you are applying the `onclick` event in all the checkboxes, you can use `var checkBox = this` to get the current checkbox

Comment: Can you show me some example code,please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way you can edit your function to work for each of the checkboxes. By changing the onclick method to `onclick="myFunction(this)` you are passing the element that triggered the onclick.

```js
function myFunction(checkBox) {
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cssExChoice">
  <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="myCheck1" onclick="myFunction(this)"> 1 : CD-ROM</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="myCheck2" onclick="myFunction(this)"> 2 : HARD DISK</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="myCheck3" onclick="myFunction(this)"> 3 : SDRAM</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="myCheck4" onclick="myFunction(this)"> 4 : REGISTER</li>
    <li>Answer
      <font id="text" style="display: none;">: 4</font>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here are some extra resources if you want a better understanding of what `this` is and how to use it:

- https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_this.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

### EDIT

To have this work for multiple questions you would need to make the following changes:

```js
function myFunction(checkBox, question) {
  var text = document.getElementById("text" + question);
  console.log(question);
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cssExChoice">
  <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="myCheck1" onclick="myFunction(this, 1)"> 1 : CD-ROM</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="myCheck2" onclick="myFunction(this, 1)"> 2 : HARD DISK</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="myCheck3" onclick="myFunction(this, 1)"> 3 : SDRAM</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="myCheck4" onclick="myFunction(this, 1)"> 4 : REGISTER</li>
    <li>Answer
      <font id="text1" style="display: none;">: 4</font>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="cssExChoice">
  <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="myCheck1" onclick="myFunction(this, 2)"> 1 : CD-ROM</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="myCheck2" onclick="myFunction(this, 2)"> 2 : HARD DISK</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="myCheck3" onclick="myFunction(this, 2)"> 3 : SDRAM</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="myCheck4" onclick="myFunction(this, 2)"> 4 : REGISTER</li>
    <li>Answer
      <font id="text2" style="display: none;">: 2</font>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But it can only run 'myfunction()' only the first question. For other question when I checked checkbox, the first question's answer was shown.

Comment: You would need to add some way to know what question they are trying to answer. You could change it to be `onclick = myFunction(this, questionNumber)` where questionNumber would be the number of that question e.g. 1. From there you would just check what question they answered in the function.

Comment: So, I would need to add assign a new variable to show question number ,right ?

Comment: Check the edit I made to my answer, that should help you. All you need to do is change the onclick for each questions to have its own questionNumber, and then change the answer text id to be `(text) + questionNumber`, so text1, text2, and so on for each answer.

Comment: Oh thank you. The function is ok. But Should we have the better way to create the questionNumber because I have so many question similar to this to edited it with replace all method. I think it's hard to edit myFunction(this) to myFunction(this, 2) with replace all

Comment: Should we assign questionNumber stay with each Question's topic

Comment: Yeah that could work, as long as each question is numbered, and there is a way you can tell what question they answered it will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
// use class instead of id for multiple tags with the same purpuse
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheck">

<script>
  // select all checkboxes
  const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.myCheck');

  // loop over all of them and add event onClick
  checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => checkbox.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (checkBox.checked == true) {
      text.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      text.style.display = "none";
    }
  }));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Element Ids must be unique across the entire document. I would also recommend using a radio button in questions to ensure that only one answer is picked.

You'll have to add the id to the answer only.

In place of the wrong answer I would recommend using a "try again" placement to allow multiple selections.

Below you'll an example, and how to model each question.

Here is an example that can be pasted into codepen.io

HTML CODE:

```
    <div class="cssExChoice"><ul>
 <li><input type="radio" name="q1" onclick="myFunction()"> 1 : CD-ROM</li>
 <li><input type="radio" name="q1" onclick="myFunction()"> 2 : HARD DISK</li>
 <li><input type="radio" name="q1" onclick="myFunction()"> 3 : SDRAM</li>
 <li><input type="radio" name="q1" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()"> 4 : REGISTER</li>
  <li>Answer: 
    <font id="text" style="display: none;">Correct</font>
    <font id="wrong" style="display: none;">Try Again</font>
  </li></ul></div>
```

Javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  var wrong = document.getElementById("wrong");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "block";
    wrong.style.display = "none";
  } else {
     text.style.display = "none";
     wrong.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

---

Below is the solution to your problem:

HTML

```
    <div class="cssExChoice"><ul>
     <li><input type="radio" name="q1" onclick="myFunction(name)"> 1 : CD-ROM</li>
     <li><input type="radio" name="q1" onclick="myFunction(name)"> 2 : HARD DISK</li>
     <li><input type="radio" name="q1" onclick="myFunction(name)"> 3 : SDRAM</li>
     <li><input type="radio" name="q1" onclick="myFunction(name)"> 4 : REGISTER</li>
      <li>Correct Answer: 
        <font id="text" style="display: none;">#4</font>
      </li></ul></div>
```

Javascript:

```
function myFunction(x) {
  var checkBox = document.getElementsByName(x);
  var text = document.getElementById("text");

  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "none";
  } else {
     text.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

The second solution allows you just label the name for each question and output the right answer every-time. It takes the "x" parameter from the name tag.

This is the exact answer to your original question, but not as great.

Comment: This is a good one. But now I have 400-500 question with html code /tag that I have to edited. I can not edit to your code with replace all in my editor.

Comment: However, It's a great idea, Thanks sir.

Comment: I'll update it right now to fit your parameters that you've included then in a second.

Comment: From your solution, I get same as another, when I checked radiobutton in next question I can show the answer of their question. It's always show only the first answer .